# Issue between nodejs and Cloudant on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, sockets, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, cloudant

I often have this kind of logs and page not responding while using NodeJs and Cloudant on Bluemix:

```
2016-03-01T17:37:49.727+0100[App/0]ERRat TLSWrap.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
2016-03-01T17:37:49.727+0100[App/0]ERRError: read ECONNRESET
2016-03-01T17:37:49.727+0100[App/0]ERRat TLSWrap.onread (net.js:544:26)
2016-03-01T17:37:49.727+0100[App/0]ERRat exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
```

It looks like it is a network problem, isn't it ?

What can I do the reset the socket transparently? I am using LoopBack framework.

Comment: Can you say more about the specific circumstances in which you are getting this kind of error? What are you trying to do?

Comment: a simple request to get a list of object from the DB. Maybe there is an unstability on Cloudant Bluemix platform theses last days than can explain this ?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the Bluemix status update page that would indicate any platform issues: https://status.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: Can you restage the app to pick up the latest buildpack and see if the problem still exists?